# Android rotate xml without any resizing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, rotateanimation

I have an activity and this is its layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

main_background is a rotate xml. There are two main_background xml for each orientation

drawable-hdpi/main_background.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/sss" >
</rotate>
```

drawable-land-hdpi/main_background.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:drawable="@drawable/sss" >
</rotate>
```

So I want to use the same .jpg file but different rotation for horizontal and vertical orientation. For example, When orientation changes to horizontal , I want to rotate drawable 90 degrees. But here is my results :

Vertical orientation (There is no problem with this):

[image: Vertical orientation]

Horizontal orientation (which is my problem):

[image: Horizontal orientation]

What i want (without any resizing):

[image: What i want]

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik you cannot do that in xml, the only way is to create a custom class extending Drawable that would react on orientarion changes for example:

```
class D extends Drawable {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private boolean mIsLandscape;

    public D(Resources res, Bitmap b) {
        mBitmap = b;
        mMatrix = new Matrix();
        mIsLandscape = res.getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF();
        if (!mIsLandscape) {
            dst.set(0, 0, bounds.width(), bounds.height());
        } else {
            dst.set(0, 0, bounds.height(), bounds.width());
        }
        mMatrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.FILL);
        if (mIsLandscape) {
            mMatrix.postRotate(-90);
            mMatrix.postTranslate(0, bounds.height());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example ? It would be great if I have a function that accepts original drawable and returns rotated drawable

Comment: class BackDrawable extends Drawable { ... and override draw() method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use two layout folders (layout-land, layout-port) and simply add

```
android:rotation="90"
```

to your -land version of the layout (well, actually, to the view using the image as a resource)

You may also have to play around with the layout-width and layout-height entries.

Alternatively, you could do this programmatically with an the view methods .rotatef() and .scalef();